# Use an object from a different model in the registerviewmodel

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-migrations

I want every user to be connected to an Organization. My Organization is defined in Organization.cs

Organization.cs

```
  public class Organization
  {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(70, MinimumLength = 3)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
  }
```

AccountViewModel.cs

```
public class RegisterViewModel
{
  [Required]
  [Display(Name = "Username")]
  public string Username { get; set; }

  [Required]
  [EmailAddress]
  [Display(Name = "Email")]
  public string Email { get; set; }

  [Required]
  public Organization myOrganization { get; set; }

  /*Rest of Model*/

}
```

In my view I want their to be a dropdown where the user selects the organization they want their account to be associated with.

Should I be adding the field like so?

```
public Organization myOrganization { get; set; }
```

Or rather should I take in the ID of the organization and then store that?

I'm using code first migrations and I would appreciate it if someone could clear up how to properly take in an object of another model and generate the database tables correctly.

My best guess is that my Organizations table and my Users table would merge into UserOrganizations, just like my Roles and Users table are merged into UserRoles to connect them both. However I am really new to all this and so I could be wrong about that.

Comment: You need properties `int SelectedOrganisation` and `IEnumerable<SelectListItem> OrganisationList` in you view model and use `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedOrganisation, Model.OrganisationList, "Please select"` in the view

Comment: Surprised you didn't write this as the answer, very good!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on whether you want to store Id or Name, storing both properties would be a bit pointless.My following example will be storing Name.Also you should **store this value to your Account table**(default table is AspNetUsers) so that each user is associated to an Organization.

You can add additional field to AspNetUsers, look into [this](http://blog.falafel.com/customize-mvc-5-application-users-using-asp-net-identity-2-0/) it is very helpful.

In your AccountViewModel there should be two properties to get things done:

1.) a list of organization names retrieved from Organization table

2.) a 'SelectedOrganizationName' as you picked from dropdownlist

And then I assume in your [HttpGet] controller you'd already load the dropdownlist with data from Organization table.On [HttpPost] controller you would do something like this:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(AccountViewModel avm)
    {                                      
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                //do add account here...
                dbcontext.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Create");
            }
            return View(avm);
        }          
        return View(avm);
    }
```

Then when you retrieve , since your Account table have the OrganizationName property you can retrieve the whole object with AccountId.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Details(int id)
    {
        Users user = dbContext.Users.Find(id);
        return View(user);
    }
```

To clarify one thing , the UserRoles table automatically created for you act as a associative entity (to resolve the many-to-many relationship between Users and Roles) but in your case, User and Organization relationship exist as one-to-one and therefore you don't need to have UserOrganizations table.

Comment: Oh ok! I thought that could be the solution, and thanks for the clarification. This really helps. Will mark as answer after I have some time to get back to my work and try some things out.

Comment: Np glad to help. :-)